# BinaryIO outputting SOH and STX instead of Int

Tags: java, binary, binaryfiles

I'm currently writing a program that will create a file and output as an integer how many times the code has been executed. this is my code:

import java.io.*;

public class Q1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int count;

    File file = new File("count.dat");

    try {
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        if (is.available() == 0)
            count = 0;
        else
            count = is.read();
        count++;
        //System.out.println(count);
        os.write(count);
        os.close();
        is.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("file not found");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IOException");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

}

I've ran into a problem with the output, when I un-comment the sysout of count it has the correct number but when I run the program and view it with notepad++ it shows soh then for the second time it outputs the soh and stx. I don't understand where these outputs are coming, any help is appreciated.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: `write` and `println` are not the same method.

Comment: the println was just for debugging purposes in order to see if the count was working properly which it is. I use os.write(count); for my actual file output (os is my fileoutputstream).

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that the output error was a problem with notepad but my file is getting overridden when I run the program.